# Angular inject service default scope

Tags: angular

I created a project using angular and trying to inject router, Here is my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
selector: 'app-stream-live-main',
templateUrl: './stream-live-main.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./stream-live-main.component.scss'],
})


export class StreamLiveMainComponent implements OnInit{


constructor(router: Router) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router.url);
}
}
```

It does not work when I do ng serve, error is

> ERROR in
>   src/app/stream/stream-live-main/stream-live-main.component.ts(19,26):
>   error TS2339: Property 'router' does not exist on type
>   'StreamLiveMainComponent'.

If add private before router: Router

```
constructor(private router: Router) {

}
```

This one works, can someone plz tell me what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that private makes the field private, i.e. not accessible from the outside TypeScript code.

Since TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, and JavaScript doesn't have the notion of private fields, it's still accessible from the outside, including the view, but making it private is still a good idea because it documents the fact that the service is... private to the class, and should thus not be used outside of the class itself, including the view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So why I cannot use this.router to access it if it is not marked as private. When I mark it as private, I can access it using this.router